# Azure AD Custom Claims in JWT

Tags: azure, sharepoint, jwt, azure-active-directory, access-token

I have an Azure AD app and I am trying to add custom claims to a JWT. I'm using the claims mapping feature in Azure for my specific app, and updated the app manifest in the Azure Portal to include the optional claims. However, when I log in and view the decoded access token, the claim is not present in the token. I haven't found much documentation relating to using extension attributes as claims, but from what I've found it should follow the same patterns, but it is not working as expected.

How do I add a custom claim, sourced from a custom property in the user object in AD, to a JWT when the user logs in?

Thanks in advance!

### Steps to re-create

1. Use the Azure AD Graph API to register a directory extension

Request:

`POST https://graph.windows.net/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/applications/<application-object-id>/extensionProperties?api-version=1.5`

Body:

```
{
   "name": "customUserRoles",
   "dataType": "String",
   "targetObjects": ["User"]
}
```

2. Write a value to the extension for a specific AD user

Request:

`PATCH https://graph.windows.net/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/users/user123@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com?api-version=1.5`

Body:

```
{
   "extension_<appId>_customUserRoles": "My Custom Role 1, Another Role 2"
}
```

3. In PowerShell, I installed the Azure AD module: `Install-Module -Name AzureADPreview`
4. Create an Azure AD policy

```
New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('{"ClaimsMappingPolicy":{"Version": 1, "IncludeBasicClaimSet": "true", "
ClaimsSchema": [ { "Source": "user", "ID": "extension_<appId>_customUserRoles", "JwtClaimType": "customUserRoles" } ] } }') -DisplayName "customUserRoles" -Type "ClaimsMappingPolicy"
```

5. Add the policy to the service principal

```
Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy -Id <service-principla-id> -RefObjectId <azure-ad-policy-id>
```

6. In the Azure Portal, navigate to Azure AD -> App Registrations -> My App -> Manifest
7. Update the following properties

```
{
   ...
   "acceptMappedClaims: true,
   "optionalClaims": {
      "idToken": [
         {
            "name": "extension_<appId>_customUserRoles",
            "source": "user",
            "essential": false,
         }
      ],
      "accessToken": [
         {
            "name": "extension_<appId>_customUserRoles",
            "source": "user",
            "essential": false,
         }
      ],
      "samlToken": []
   }
}
```

8. Save the file
9. Navigate to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<appId>&response_type=token&resource=https://mytenant.sharepoint.com` and login with Azure AD user account `user123@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com`
10. In the URL, copy the value of the `access_token` parameter
11. Navigate to `https://jwt.ms` and paste the access token in the text area
12. In the decoded token section, the custom claim *customUserRoles* is **not** present

My expectation is I should see a new claim called `customUserRoles` or `extn.customUserRoles` in the decoded token.

What steps am I missing? I haven't gotten any errors throughout this process, but it doesn't appear to be working as the documentation suggests.

---

### Reference Material

I have read through Microsoft's documentation on these topics:

Optional Claims: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims

Claims Mapping: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-claims-mapping

---

I have also read through various forum posts and blog articles relating to this:

https://devonblog.com/cloud/azure-ad-adding-employeeid-claims-in-azure-ad-jwt-token/

http://www.redbaronofazure.com/?p=7566

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3e5114b6-24d6-4c60-b72b-b4c90baeecac/access-token-missing-optional-claims-that-are-schema-extensions-implicit-grant-flow

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dbeeed63-8d3f-4c27-b416-431f9fe6c729/providing-directory-extension-optional-claims-and-returning-value-within-token?forum=WindowsAzureAD

Comment: I think you won't be able to get custom claims in the access tokens for an API you did not create. Access tokens targeting your app's API as well as Id tokens received by your app could contain them as I understand.

Comment: If specific claim has the value then it would be appear in the token. Null value completely obsolete from token. Check the value in user profile by calling graph.microsoft.com beta endpoint.

Like: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/bece0bec-5c80-4295-9275-08b072e74z10

and see the value.

Answer (score 7):

Based on [this official](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims#configuring-optional-claims) doc :

> Access tokens are always generated using the manifest of the resource,
>   not the client. So in the request
>   ...scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read... the resource is
>   Graph. Thus, the access token is created using the Graph manifest, not
>   the client's manifest. Changing the manifest for your application will
>   never cause tokens for Graph to look different. In order to validate
>   that your accessToken changes are in effect, request a token for your
>   application, not another app.

And based on your requirement , it is impossible if you want to make some change on an access token which resource is sharepoint online which is a multi-tenant app created and managed by MSFT.

For [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-claims-mapping) , I also did some research for you . And the same , you should have control of the service side app so that you can make that happen.

This is my policy role assignment command :

```
$nsp = New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('{"ClaimsMappingPolicy":{"Version":1,"IncludeBasicClaimSet":"true", "ClaimsSchema": [{"Source":"user","ID":"mailnickname","JwtClaimType":"testclaim"}]}}') -DisplayName "StanCustomCliamDemo_surname" -Type "ClaimsMappingPolicy"

Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy  -RefObjectId $nsp.Id -Id '<obj id of service side app>'
```

Token result : 
[image]

What's more , pls note that `extension_<appId>_customUserRoles` is not a valid user source ID . For all valid user source ID , pls refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-claims-mapping#table-3-valid-id-values-per-source) .

Hope it helps .

Comment: doesnt work for me for service principal app registration and customly extended field...

Comment: @Stanley, I have a similar requirement. I want to add some custom user-defined claims to azure ad access token. My requirement exactly matches this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60569243/how-to-set-custom-claims-to-aad-token-using-c-sharp-code

Comment: @stanleyGong How did you pass the value 'stan' is this dynamically passed during the request while you try to get the token?

Answer (score 0):

Few years late on this one but for anyone coming to this in 2023. It's not particularly well documented but if you want to map an extentionAttribute into the JWT you need to use the property `ExtensionID` in the `ClaimsSchema` object rather than `ID`.

So:

```
New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('{"ClaimsMappingPolicy":{"Version": 1, "IncludeBasicClaimSet": "true", "ClaimsSchema": [ { "Source": "user", "ID": "extension_<appId>_customUserRoles", "JwtClaimType": "customUserRoles" } ] } }') -DisplayName "customUserRoles" -Type "ClaimsMappingPolicy"
```

Becomes:

```
New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('{"ClaimsMappingPolicy":{"Version": 1, "IncludeBasicClaimSet": "true","ClaimsSchema": [ { "Source": "user", "ExtensionID": "extension_<appId>_customUserRoles", "JwtClaimType": "customUserRoles" } ] } }') -DisplayName "customUserRoles" -Type "ClaimsMappingPolicy"
```